# How to remove single character a a time from a textbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm implementing a set of buttons which when pressed type alphanumeric characters in a textbox.

How can I implement backspace button so that whenever it is pressed, the last character in the textbox is erased from the textbox?

Answer (score 5):

Try the below (`Javascript`)code on the press of a button...

```
var mytxtbx=document.getElementById("IdOfTextBox");
mytxtbx.value=mytxtbx.value.substring(0,(mytxtbx.value.length-1))
```

Try the below (`JQuery`)code on the press of a button...

```
$("#IdOfTextBox").val($("#IdOfTextBox").val().substring(0,($("#IdOfTextBox").val().length-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Though already answered, you might cleanup his code a bit and "cache" some variables:

```
function RemoveLastChar(){
    var field = $("#fieldID");
    var oldValue = field.val();
    field.val(oldValue.substring(0, oldValue.length - 1));
}
```